# Change/ Set date format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need an option to set the date format. This is my starting point ! Some suggestions

```
          <md-select ng-model="date.format">
            <md-option value="1">yyyy-mm-dd</md-option>
            <md-option value="2">mm/dd/yyyy</md-option>
            <md-option value="3">mm/dd/yy</md-option>
          </md-select>

<md-button ng-click="saveDate(date.format)">Save</md-button>
```

Comment: What you've posted looks fine. Without any additional context, it's not clear what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. Now just use the angular date filter with the pattern you have selected. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date